# Argument of type '{ test3: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ test1: any; test2: any; area: any; }'

Tags: typescript

```js
export function ra({ test1, test2, test3 }) {
    if(test1) {
        return `test1`
    } else if(test2) {
        return `test2`
    }
    if(test3) {
        return `test3`
    }
}
console.log(ra({ test1: "a" }))
```

My error is `Argument of type '{ test3: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ test1: any; test2: any; area: any; }'.`

I'm doing this for a school project and I don't understand the error

Answer (score 1):

You are missing key/value pairs in the arguments Object, you have `test1` but are missing `test2` and `test3`

For example, this will work

```js
console.log(ra({ test1: "a" , test2: "a", test3: "a"}))
```

If you did this on purpose, you have to explicitly type your parameters to allow optional key/value pairs with the `?`. Otherwise TypeScript's default behavior is to expect they will be defined.

```js
type ra2Parameters = {
  test1?: string;
  test2?: string;
  test3?: string;
}

export function ra2({ test1, test2, test3 }: ra2Parameters) {
    if(test1) {
        return `test1`
    } else if(test2) {
        return `test2`
    } 
    if (test3) {
        return `test3`
    }
}

//This will work now
console.log(ra2({ test1: "a" }))
```

[View this on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=33&pln=33&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVygQwAoBvOGYAZxgEYAaMymAJnvKoGY4BfASjmIBQcYXEwJCbGn0EjZeYDCRRcAA0nUVQkVzjAANhWCjxkptK1z5i5XDWMmm2VwvG4Exu3OXhUBUtWS7I7aAs5oOBQQesAAdHoQAOaEBCQMVNQAXHAARPjZ3Dw8AsXhKJHRcYnJRKTqWbn5rPb1eU0cLdm8RQIwAJ5gRgRMAAr4BAC2CsBQFHAAvPxa6gD8WVRQmCgJANxL9qtw65s7exwHR1u7zgKgkLCIqBjYuEOp6m3MH5xcWUOjE1MZl4RGJ3OlgZZfNYAowNC4dPpDMYwcwIXIof5bKZgsIdC4xG5AmjZBibHYODjuKEShEorF4klXrVYR0CjwgA)